# this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL for no reason

Tags: android, http, permissions

OK, I'm getting this error for no reason. Because my app starts and everything works fine.
But when it wants to send a HTTP request it crashes and logcat shows this error.

And I'm getting this error only on real devices, It works just fine in the emulator.

My app doesn't need such permissions really. It's so simple. 
I know I did something wrong in the code and this has nothing to do with such permissions.
But I can't figure it out where did I do wrong.

This is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="ir.Ava.android"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="5"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Avatheme" 
        android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" android:supportsRtl="true">
        <!-- Splash screen -->
        <activity
            android:name="ir.Ava.android.SplashScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Main activity -->
        <activity
            android:name="ir.Ava.android.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="ir.Ava.android.Bubble"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And this is the fragment that causes the problem:

```
inside MainActivity.java

public static class profileSectionFragment extends Fragment {

    TextView testText;
    // flag for Internet connection status
    Boolean isInternetPresent = false;
    Button editPFButton;
    // Connection detector class
    ConnectionDetector cd;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile, container, false);
        ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pf_username)).setText("Name of the user");
        testText = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.testText);

        // Buttons
        editPFButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.edit_profile);

        editPFButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Context appContext = getActivity().getApplicationContext();

                // creating connection detector class instance
                cd = new ConnectionDetector(appContext);

                // get Internet status
                isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();



                // check for Internet status
                if (isInternetPresent) {
                    testText.setText("successfully connected to the internet");
                } else {
                    testText.setText("there is no internet connection");
                }


                // Creating HTTP client
                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                // Creating HTTP Post
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(
                        "http://192.168.1.2/android/");

                // Building post parameters
                // key and value pair
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", "user@gmail.com"));
                nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message",
                        "Hi, trying Android HTTP post!"));

                // Url Encoding the POST parameters
                try {
                    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    // writing error to Log
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                // Making HTTP Request
                try {
                    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                    Log.d("HTTP Response:", response.toString());

                     if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200)
                     {
                         HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                         testText.setText(EntityUtils.toString(entity));
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         testText.setText("Error: "+response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
                     }

                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    // writing exception to log
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // writing exception to log
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }

            }
        });


        return rootView;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post the exact error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not allowed to do network I/O on the main (UI) thread. You should use an `AsyncTask` instead. For example:

```
final TextView testText = ...

AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>()
{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params)
    {
        ... Create HTTP client, and everything as before ...

        // Making HTTP Request
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        Log.d("HTTP Response:", response.toString());

        if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200)
        {
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            return EntityUtils.toString(entity);
        }
        else
        {
            return "Error: "+response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result)
    {
        testText.setText(result);
    }
};

task.execute();
```

Comment: Thank you so much! finally! someone who knows something. :)